# How to use Hotjar on Electron?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, electron, cross-browser, hotjar

According to Hotjar [documentation](https://help.hotjar.com/hc/en-us/articles/115012499507-Platforms-and-Frameworks-not-Compatible-with-Hotjar), Hotjar does not support Electron because

> Since you use it to create desktop applications and not web applications the Hotjar tracking code cannot be used.

Is there any way to make this work?